# Get first created document from CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, document

I know how to get the last document created by couchDB :

```
http://<IP>:5984/<DBname>/_changes?descending=true&limit=1
```

But my question is how to get the doc ID of the first document?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the *descending=true* parameter from the URL and use only `http://<IP>:5984/<DBname>/_changes?limit=1`. However, according to the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html):

> Only the most recent change for a given document is guaranteed to be provided, for example if a document has had fields added, and then deleted, an API client checking for changes will not necessarily receive the intermediate state of added documents.

So if the first document has been modified, it won't appear as the first item in the changes feed.

A way to achieve this would be to add a date_created timestamp in the documents when they are created and use a view that emits this field so that the documents are sorted by creation time.